# Flutter- Send local notification on my device at device's local time 8:00 PM every day by using the flutter_local_notification

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, alarm

Send **local notification** on my device at device's **local time 8:00 PM** every day by using the flutter_local_notification

Like alarm app even if app terminate or kill from background notification should have to recive

I can implement firebase also if possible thre firebase push notification

Method i want that calls in background if app is in background or not(Means app is removed from background)